# Blocking capacitor? Driving 8 ohm .5 watt speaker with microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, capacitor, speakers

I'm reading *Make: AVR Programming*. The next project wants me to try to drive an 8 ohm speaker with a pin from the microcontroller.

I'm no EE, but I do know that 8 ohms is not a lot of resistance, and it seems like  we're going to run into problems running too much current through the microcontroller pin.

The book's solution is to use a "blocking capacitor". For some reason, I'm still a bit skeptical this is safe for my microcontroller. There are no resistors anywhere in sight. Here is the page from the book:

[image: Blocking capacitor diagram]

**Question:** if I don't care about sound quality, is this circuit safe for my microcontroller? The maximum current is supposed to be 40mA per pin.

Comment: i would put a 500ohms in series with the avr (OR replace the cap with a smaller 20-30nF cap). Either option will limit the current.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whoever wrote that page is criminally wrong. The blocking capacitor is only an open to DC. The AC current will still be much higher than the AVR's absolute maximum. As a minimum, put a push pull buffer between the micro and speaker. I would rather see a low side switch.

Comment: @Jakerc You might want to throw that book away.

Comment: Looked into it further, the author has a Ph.D in Economics, was a career statistician, and considers himself an electronics hacker, explains everything.

Comment: Thanks, guys. @Austin, it's a book from the library, so I don't think that's my best option, but I'm glad to hear my skepticism was well-founded.